# reading from text file to two dimensional array

Tags: file-io, multidimensional-array

I try to read a text file and pass all integers to a 2 dimensional array one by one. But when i print what I tried to pass, I get weird outputs. What could be the problem?
For example if the text is:
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1

I get this:

index=-2 index=1967626458 index=1967694074 index=207568 index=207320 index=2686776 index=1967693597 index=0 index=0 index=2686832 index=236 index=228 index=3

Here is the code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {

    FILE *input;
    //read file!
     if((input = fopen("abc.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("Error in reading file !\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int C = 4;
    int R = 3;
    int M[3][4];
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int c;
    //array of sorted list!
    while(!feof(input)){
        if(!feof(input)){

            fscanf( input, "%d",&c);


         M[x][y]=c;
            y++;
            if(y==C){

            x++;
            y=0;


            }
    printf("index=%d \n",M[x][y]);
         }
     }
       system("pause");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printout is wrong because you're changing the values of x and y between when you set the variable and when you try to print it. You need to move the `printf()` before the part where you increment `x` and `y`, but after you assign to the array.

As it stands right now, you assign to the array, then print the next, as yet unassigned, value. It's whatever value happens to be in that memory, such as -2 or 1967626458.

Answer (score 0):

just increment you `y` variable after printing index.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *input;
    //read file!
    if((input = fopen("abcd.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in reading file !\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int C = 4;
    int R = 3;
    int M[3][4];
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int c;
    //array of sorted list!
    while(!feof(input))
    {
        if(!feof(input))
        {

            fscanf( input, "%d",&c);


            M[x][y]=c;
            //y++ ; not increment here
            if(y==C)
            {
                x++;
                y=0;
            }
            printf("index=%d \n",M[x][y]);
            y++;//increment here
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```